# How to operate random node for Shortest Path?

Tags: matlab, random

Let n = 10;
Then, how can we use random nodes (replaces X & Y values) to generate shortest path such as below code:

```
x= [1 1 2 2 3 4 6 4 5 5 ];    
y= [2 5 3 4 4 5 3 1 2 6 ];

% Random weight for shortestpath
weights = randi(52, size(x));    
w = randi([1 10], 13, 1); 

D = graph(x,y,weights);    
p = plot(D,'x','EdgeLabel',D.Edges.Weight );

path = shortestpath(D,1,5);    
highlight(p,path,'NodeColor','g','EdgeColor','g')
```

Thanks.

Comment: you just want to know how to create random numbers? you're already doing thst in your code for the weights. or do you need something more specific (nodes have to have some order or min distance between or something?)

Comment: No, the weights is for metric. I just want to make it the node randomly distributed in 100x100 area.